# How can I declare and unpack an array of pairs of void pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

I would like to write a function that takes an array of `void*` "pairs" - each one is a pair of pointers to something. The first element in each pair will be a string, and the second will be a pointer to something else.

I would like the array passed into the function to be declared like so:

```
<what type?> argument = {
        { "some string", <some pointer>},
        { "some other string", <some other pointer>},
        // ... etc
        NULL // To signal ending
}

function(argument);
```

Inside `function`, I would like to iterate over the array, access each "pair", cast the members of the "pair" to their respective types (known to me) and make use of these members.

I'm having some trouble with this. At first, I tried declaring the argument as `void* thing[][]`. Thinking it's an array of arrays of `void` pointers.

However, simply trying to access an index in such an array gives me the error: `expression must be a pointer to a complete object type`.

Reading on SO I realized the compiler is thinking I'm trying to dereference a `void*`. But I thought that doing `a[0]` on such an array would access the first "pair" in the array, which should be dereferencing a `void**` - which is legal. Am I wrong?

What is the correct approach to go about this, in terms of the type of the array, it's initialization and the way to unpack the array during iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `void *argument[][2] = { /* ... */ };`. You have an array of unspecified size, whose elements are arrays of fixed size 2, whose elements are pointers to `void`. Your original compiler error was because when you have multiple square braces, only the first set of them can be empty, so adding the `2` fixed it.

By the way, it can decay as a pointer, in which case it would be `void *(*argument)[2]`.

Note that your sentinel `NULL` doesn't do quite what you'd expect, since it's in an array of arrays, and arrays aren't quite pointers. Note this warning:

```
warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
        NULL // To signal ending
        ^~~~
        {   }
```

Here's a sample program that uses the type:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *g[][2] = {
        { "some string", (void*)0x1234},
        { "some other string", (void*)0x5678},
        { "some third string", (void*)0x9abc},
        // ... etc
        {NULL} // To signal ending
};


void print_things(void *argument[][2]) {
    for(int i = 0; argument[i][0] /* using just argument[i] instead of argument[i][0] here would not work as intended */; ++i) {
        printf("%s %p\n", (char*)argument[i][0], argument[i][1]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    print_things(g);
    return 0;
}
```

As a final note, I'd say your life would probably be simpler with a custom `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct pair {
    char *str;
    void *ptr;
} g[] = {
        { "some string", (void*)0x1234},
        { "some other string", (void*)0x5678},
        { "some third string", (void*)0x9abc},
        // ... etc
        {NULL, NULL} // To signal ending
};


void print_things(struct pair argument[]) {
    for(int i = 0; argument[i].str; ++i) {
        printf("%s %p\n", argument[i].str, argument[i].ptr);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    print_things(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Two questions: 1. You mention that `void *argument[][2] = { /* ... */ };` is "an array of variable size". By "array of variable size", do you mean "variable length array"? And if so, isn't this statement false? Isn't a variable length array an array whose size is determined by a runtime value, while the size of the array in question is simply implicitly determined during compile time by the right hand expression?

Comment: Secondly: you mentioned that "only the first square bracket can be empty". Can you elaborate on that? Is this because the compiler can implicitly understand the size of the outermost array by inspecting the right side value, but still needs specified sizes for the inner arrays? Or is this for another reason? (Assuming this indeed is *not* a "variable length array", if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Actually, a third question if I might :) I understand now that `void *argument[][2]` means "an array of arrays-of-2 of pointers to void". I.e., we read it "from the center out". However - I'm having problems reading the equivalent pointer type: `void *(*argument[2])`. Essentially, what is this and how should we "read this"? Reading "from the center out", is this read as "pointer to array-of-two of pointers to void"? If so, why are the parentheses necessary in this syntax?
Thanks!

Comment: 1. I should have said "unspecified size". A variable-length array is a specific means of creating an array that's not of fixed size, and it's not the one being used here. 2. If more than the first square bracket were empty, then the size of the array elements would be unknown, so the compiler wouldn't know the offset of `argument[1]`. 3. You're correct on what that type is. You need the parentheses because without them, `void **argument[2]` would mean "an array-of-2 of pointers to pointers to void", which isn't the type we want.

Comment: Hi, I took the opportunity to learn the precedence rules for type expressions. I think `void *(*argument[2])` might be a mistake? I think it means "argument is array of two of pointers to pointers to void". Isn't `void *(*argument)[2]` the correct way to declare "argument is pointer to array of 2 of pointer to void"?

Comment: @AvivCohen Whoops, you're right indeed! I typed one thing in my test program and a different one here. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: One more thing! As the sentinel at the end of the array, I tried putting the following three options: `{NULL, NULL}`, `{NULL}` and also simply `NULL` (no curly braces). All of them seem to work the same (and also no warnings with default compiler warning settings). Why should they work differently? In terms of the way the data is laid out in memory, isn't `{NULL}` equivalent to `NULL`? (Just trying to gain the best understanding I can). Thanks!

Comment: @AvivCohen They do all work the same. If none give you warnings with the defaults, try enabling more warnings. (FWIW, `clang -Weverything` will *definitely* show it to you.)

Comment: If so what is the danger of just using `NULL`? Isn't the memory layout the same? Can you point me in the direction of reading material on this?

Comment: @AvivCohen it's not dangerous; it's guaranteed to do the right thing. The reason that clang gives you a warning is that it will confuse people looking at the code later, and that makes it more likely that a modification to the code will be wrong.